# How do scopes influence keys in a build? What is a scope axis?

Tags: sbt

I am trying to understand what [SBT scope axes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html) are and how they influence scoped keys in the map of the build.

There are three scope axes : `project`, `configuration` and `task`.

1. Is the following tuple the scoped key for the map of the build?

   (value of project axis, value of configuration axis, value of task axis, value of unscoped key)
2. Or is a scoped key (conceptually) a pair having one of the following three forms ?

   (value of project axis, value of unscoped key)

   (value of configuration axis, value of unscoped key)

   (value of task axis, value of unscoped key)
3. Or is the scoped key something else, if yes how does it look like (conceptually) ?

So the question could be what is (conceptually) a scoped key?

1. Is it a four tuple?
2. Is it a pair?
3. Is it something else, if yes, then how does it looks like (conceptually)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Custom settings and tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Custom-Settings.html):

> Keys have one of three types: `SettingKey`, `TaskKey` and `InputKey`.

An example of a key can be:

```
val scalaVersion = settingKey[String]("The version of Scala used for building.")
```

It's available by default in sbt and to query for a value you execute `show`:

```
> show scalaVersion
[info] 2.10.4
```

Execute `inspect` to learn about the details of a key (it's not exactly about a key but a setting as you soon learn):

```
> inspect scalaVersion
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = 2.10.4
[info] Description:
[info]  The version of Scala used for building.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:236
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:libraryDependencies
[info]  *:scalaInstance
[info]  *:evicted
[info]  *:dependencyUpdatesData
[info]  *:update
[info]  *:allDependencies
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:scalaVersion
[info]  {.}/*:scalaVersion
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
```

You can define your own key with the macro `settingKey`:

```
lazy val abc: sbt.SettingKey[String] = settingKey[String]("My own setting key")
```

According to the scaladoc of [sbt.SettingKey](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/#sbt.SettingKey):

> Identifies a setting. It consists of three parts: the scope, the name, and the type of a value associated with this key. The scope is represented by a value of type Scope. The name and the type are represented by a value of type AttributeKey[T]. Instances are constructed using the companion object.

As you can see in the scaladoc, any `SettingKey` has the required `def scope: Scope` that describes the scope of the setting. Soon to be explained.

You can't see the key in the build until you assign it a value (via a computation). You assign an `Initialize[T]` or just `T` to a `SettingKey[T]` via `:=`, `+=` and `++=` (more often used and recommended) or `<++=`, `<+=` and `<<=` operators (that are Scala methods described in the scaladoc of [sbt.SettingKey](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/#sbt.SettingKey)).

```
abc := "my value"
```

The above line is equivalent to the following line (they're interchangeable):

```
abc.:=("my value")
```

As you can see in the definition of `:=`:

```
final def :=(v: T): Def.Setting[T]
```

the result of it is `Setting[T]`.

So, the pair (`SettingKey[T]`, `Initialize[T]`) or simply (`SettingKey[T]`, `T`) is a `Setting[T]`.

A setting of type `Setting[T]` where `T` is the type of the value that is a result of the setting's evaluation describes a transformation to the map of all the settings in a build. It's a recipe for a value that's going to be available under a key after the build's loaded.

Now, the last part, the scope.

As you may've noticed, a setting is always in a scope. You can change the scope of a setting using `final def in(scope: Scope): SettingKey[T]`.

Use `inspect` to learn about a setting.

```
> inspect abc
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = my value
[info] Description:
[info]  My new setting key
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-theory/}sbt-theory/*:abc
[info] Defined at:
[info]  /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-theory/build.sbt:3
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:abc
[info]  {.}/*:abc
[info]  */*:abc
```

You can see that the setting delegates (section `Delegates`) to `*:abc`, `{.}/*:abc` and `*/*:abc`. The other places that I'm going to describe as `A/B:K` are `A` - the project axis, `B` - the configuration axis and `K` the key or the task scope (since sbt allows for attibutes that appear after `::`).

Guess what the value of `*:abc` is. `inspect` it.

```
> inspect *:abc
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = my value
[info] Description:
[info]  My new setting key
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-theory/}sbt-theory/*:abc
[info] Defined at:
[info]  /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-theory/build.sbt:3
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:abc
[info]  {.}/*:abc
[info]  */*:abc
```

Guess what the value of `{.}/*:abc` that corresponds to this build denoted as `{.}` in the global configuration `*`. `inspect` it.

```
> inspect {.}/*:abc
[info] No entry for key.
[info] Description:
[info]  My new setting key
[info] Delegates:
[info]  {.}/*:abc
[info]  */*:abc
[info] Related:
[info]  *:abc
```

There's no value for `abc` setting in `ThisBuild` (aka `thisBuild`) scope. Set it in `build.sbt` using:

```
abc in ThisBuild := "abc in ThisBuild"
```

`inspect` it (after `reload` to reload the build's changes):

```
> inspect {.}/*:abc
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = abc in ThisBuild
[info] Description:
[info]  My new setting key
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-theory/}/*:abc
[info] Defined at:
[info]  /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-theory/build.sbt:5
[info] Delegates:
[info]  {.}/*:abc
[info]  */*:abc
[info] Related:
[info]  *:abc
```

With the change `build.sbt` looks as follows:

```
lazy val abc: sbt.SettingKey[String] = settingKey[String]("My new setting key")

abc := "my value"

abc in ThisBuild := "abc in ThisBuild"
```

that says that there's `abc` key that has different values per scope - `ThisBuild` and `Global`. Clear? Ask away!

Comment: Thank **you**! Keep asking until it's complete (and can become part of the official documentation - that's my wish).

Comment: What do you mean by "You assign an Initialize[T] to a SettingKey[T] " ? According to the doc, the := method takes a value of type T. I am confused. How is a T an Initialize[T] ? Are they related by inheritance ?

Comment: I'll have to fix that since `Initialize[T]` is in `<`-like operators that are less frequently used (and recommended for more advanced uses).

Comment: What happens if there are two configuration axis values, say C1 and C2 and there are two project axis values P1 and P2, in that case how many different values can abc have ? Nine? Three times three ? Because config axis can be : *,C1,C2 and project axis can be {.},P1,P2?

Comment: It's a cartesian product of all the axes as you can see with `inspect` and `Delegates`. I'd say there are going to be more then nine since there are already many configurations available, `Compile`, `Test`, `Runtime` and few more.

Comment: So the answer to my original question is Option 1? That is the one that expresses cartesian product. So axes might be also called dimensions?

Comment: Think so. There could be at least 9 different values for a setting. Just do the exercise yourself since it's soooo easy in sbt :)